# How do I read twitter data saved in a txt file?

Tags: python, regex, twitter, tweepy, data-cleaning

I have used the twitter streaming API to gather a large number of tweets in python.

All tweets are dumped in a txt file.

```
{"created_at":"Sun Jul 03 15:23:11 +0000 2016","id":749624538015621120,"id_str":"749624538015621120","text":"Et hop un petit muldo dor\u00e9-indigo #enroutepourlaG2","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":3050686557,"id_str":"3050686557","name":"Heresia","screen_name":"Air_Et_Zia","location":null,"url":null,"description":"Joueur de Dofus depuis 6 ans. Essentiellement ax\u00e9 PvP. Actuellement sur #Amayiro !","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":296,"friends_count":30,"listed_count":0,"favourites_count":23,"statuses_count":216,"created_at":"Sat Feb 21 20:45:02 +0000 2015","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":"fr","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"000000","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"9266CC","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"000000","profile_text_color":"000000","profile_use_background_image":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/569237837581545472\/e_OJaGOl_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/569237837581545472\/e_OJaGOl_normal.png","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"enroutepourlaG2","indices":[34,50]}],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"fr","timestamp_ms":"1467559391870"}
```

1. How do I read individual tweet text of hundreds of tweets?
2. Can I save tweets with a particular tag into another text file?For example tweets which contain the word "Indigo" will be stored in another text file.

Only solution I can think of is using Regular Expressions. Are there any better solutions in python?

Comment: Are they on separate lines? If so, you could process each line as `json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since what you have is valid JSON, you can use a JSON parser:

```
import json

json_string = r'''{"created_at":"Sun Jul 03 15:23:11 +0000 2016","id":749624538015621120,"id_str":"749624538015621120","text":"Et hop un petit muldo dor\u00e9-indigo #enroutepourlaG2","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":3050686557,"id_str":"3050686557","name":"Heresia","screen_name":"Air_Et_Zia","location":null,"url":null,"description":"Joueur de Dofus depuis 6 ans. Essentiellement ax\u00e9 PvP. Actuellement sur #Amayiro !","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":296,"friends_count":30,"listed_count":0,"favourites_count":23,"statuses_count":216,"created_at":"Sat Feb 21 20:45:02 +0000 2015","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":"fr","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"000000","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"9266CC","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"000000","profile_text_color":"000000","profile_use_background_image":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/569237837581545472\/e_OJaGOl_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/569237837581545472\/e_OJaGOl_normal.png","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"enroutepourlaG2","indices":[34,50]}],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"fr","timestamp_ms":"1467559391870"}'''

twit = json.loads(json_string)
print (json.dumps(twit["text"]))#or any string manipulation here
```

Output:

> "Et hop un petit muldo dor\u00e9-indigo #enroutepourlaG2"
> => None

---

And, *please*, keep this advice in mind:

#### Regex is for string match. Never, ever, use it to parse (x)HTML, JSON, XML, CSV or any format that can be parsed. Use a parser instead.

You'll save a **lot** of time.